Solution of Cauchy problem by Kirchhoﬀ’s formula
while studying the Cauchy problem
\begin{array}{l}
{u_{tt}} - {\nabla ^2}u = 0,x \in {\mathbb{R}^3}\\ 
u\left( {x,0} \right) = 0\\ 
{u_t}\left( {x,0} \right) = f\left( {x} \right)
\end{array}
the solution provided in the research is very concise. It has
$u(x,{\rm{ }}t){\rm{ }} = \frac{1}{{4\pi t}}\int\limits_{\partial B(x,t)} {f(y)} d{S_y}$
But when I substitute it into ${u_{tt}} - {\nabla ^2}u$, I cannot make the equation equal to zero. So, I'm asking for advice on how to solve it. Here is my derivation process:
$\begin{array}{l}
{u_t}{\rm{ }} =  - \frac{1}{{4\pi {t^2}}}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,1)} {f(x + zt)} d{S_z} + \frac{1}{{4\pi t}}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,1)} {z\nabla f(x + zt)} d{S_z}\\
{u_{tt}}{\rm{ }} = \frac{1}{{2\pi {t^3}}}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,1)} {f(x + zt)} d{S_z} - \frac{1}{{2\pi {t^2}}}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,1)} {z\nabla f(x + zt)} d{S_z} + \frac{1}{{4\pi t}}\int\limits_{\partial B(0,1)} {{z^2}{\nabla ^2}f(x + zt)} d{S_z}\\
{u_{tt}} - {\nabla ^2}u = \frac{1}{{2\pi {t^3}}}\int\limits_{\partial B(x,t)} {f(y)} d{S_y} - \frac{1}{{2\pi {t^3}}}\int\limits_{\partial B(x,t)} {\left| {y - x} \right|\nabla f(y)} d{S_z}\\
 = \frac{1}{{2\pi {t^3}}}\int\limits_{\partial B(x,t)} {\left( {f(y) - \left| {y - x} \right|\nabla f(y)} \right)} d{S_y}
\end{array}$

then you should show your calculations at the very least… or look at the derivation of Kirchoff’s formula and backtrace to see where you went wrong.
